# What's this operation on an element of a set of a family called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $S = \{1,...,n\}$, and $F$ be a family of subsets of $S$. Then given $k \in S$, define $F_k$ as a new family generated from $F$, by adding $k$ to every set in $F$ that does not contain $k$ and removing it otherwise. For example:

$$S=\{1,2,3,4\}, \ F=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}, \ k = 2$$ then

$$F_2 = \{\{2\},\{1\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,3,4\}\}.$$

I am not very familiar with set theory, so I wonder if anyone has ever seen this kind of operation? Does $F_k$ have a name and some properties? Is there theorems/lectures/books/papers/etc. regarding this, so I can gather information about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a function $f_k \colon \operatorname{Powerset}(S) \to \operatorname{Powerset}(S)$, $f_k(X) = X \cup \{k\}$ if $k \not \in X$, and $f_k(X) = X \setminus \{k\}$ otherwise? And then you set $F_k = f(F)?$ Because "adding or removing the $k$-th element" does not make much sense, since sets are in general not ordered.

Comment: Yes! Writing it like this seems overly specific then; I still hope that I can find something where they talk about it though.

Comment: Here is the thing: we (mathematicians) in general don't give everything a name, unless it is of some degree of importance. I don't think there is any reason for this operation to be extremely useful. If you need it, you just define it when needed.

Comment: I just want to know if it has any properties, hoping that someone might have encountered it and explored it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should clarify the context of how did you encounter this notion and why you think this notion is important to you. Not every question contain these factors, but this is important in your case since few people are familiar with the notions in your question. Clarifying the context would be helpful to get better feedback.

I also agree with the comment by @Ray that not every notion has a name. In fact, not everything must have a name: if we name something that is not important, we would forget it.

However, there is an algebraic characterization of the notion in your question that seems worth mentioning. Remember that the symmetric difference
$$A\mathrel{\triangle}B := (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$
makes the set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of all subsets of $X$ an abelian group. That is, $(\mathcal{P}(S),\triangle)$ is an abelian group.
Then your operation corresponds to a pointwise *addition* (symmetric difference) of a singleton.

In the case of your example, let $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $F=\{\varnothing,\{1,2\}, \{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(S)$, and $a=\{2\}$. You can see that $F_2=\{x\mathrel{\triangle} a\mid a\in F\}$.